# Return control from shell script to parent python script

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I am calling a shell script from within a python script:

```
Process=subprocess.Popen('shell_script.sh %s %s' % (str(var1),str(var2),),shell=True)
```

The process within the shell script finishes (It is executing a java class using the 'java' command inside this script) and produces some output folders

However the control never comes back to the parent python script. What could i be doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it possible to use either
`subprocess.check_call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None)`
or
`subprocess.check_output(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False, cwd=None, encoding=None, errors=None, universal_newlines=False, timeout=None)`

Instead? Those may return control to you as call works differently than popen with regard to control.

Comment: Also make your command safe: `['shell_script.sh', str(var1), str(var2)]`!

Comment: Have you tried to run `shell_script.sh` from the command line to see if it ever finish?

Comment: @Hai Vu yes the script finishes independently.

Comment: @enbay1 I am unable to format the command to use check_call. I need to pass in 2 arguments to the shell script and I dont have control over the shell script to make any changes there. Does this look okay- subprocess.check_call('shell_script.sh %s %s' % (str(var1),str(var2),)', *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None)

Comment: Calling `Popen` should return control to you immediately - not waiting for the subprocess to finish. What is the next line in your code and what is it supposed to do?

Comment: If you're on windows you can run this and see that all three give the same output. Or you can change "dir" to "ls" and "/D" to "-l" and "/N" to "-a" and see for yourself on any other OS.
`import subprocess
print("\n".join(subprocess.check_output("dir /D /N", shell=True).decode("utf-8").split(",")))

print("\n".join(subprocess.check_output("dir {} {}".format("/D", "/N"), shell=True).decode("utf-8").split(",")))

print("\n".join(subprocess.check_output('dir %s %s' % ("/D","/N",), shell=True).decode("utf-8").split(",")))`